# facing issue with login page in redux or react-redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

**I have created a login page in app.js then actions and then reducers**

**Reducer Function:**

```
const loginAuth = (state = username + password, action) => {
    
        console.log('this user ' + state);
        switch (action.type) {
            case "LOGIN": return state === username && state === password ? alert('true') : alert('false');
            default: return state;
        }
    
    };
```

**Below Action:**

```
 export const login = (username, password) => {
        return {
            type: "LOGIN",
        }
    };
```

**Html and JSX:**

````
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form>
          <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} required />
          <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} required/>
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} required />
          <input type="submit" value="Login" onClick={() => dispatch(login())} />
        </form>
      </div>```
````

Comment: Did you have a question?  Is something specific not working in some way?  At a glance, I don't see how this condition could ever be true: `state === username && state === password` unless you require users to use their usernames as their passwords, which would be a terrible idea.

Comment: yes above code is not working, once user put their username and password then it should work hence I have created actions and reducers.
What could be the solution?